# How to handle email input validation in AngularJS with Twitter Bootstrap styling?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, input

[**Live Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VcSapDdaRdNo6WHDBs04?p=preview)

Consider an email input:

```html
<input type="email" ng-model="client.email">
```

If one types `a@b` in it, `client.email` stays `undefined`, but the input is not considered [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ainvalid).

If one uses [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) to style the inputs, this causes the input to have a normal blue outline, rather than the red one, which suggests that the input has a valid email.

This is quite confusing because users think they entered a valid email address, but the underlying model in AngularJS is not set.

Any recommendations how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your use of Bootstrap is what confused you. If you add the styles yourself for ng-invalid / ng-valid classes, you will see that it's an error.

For instance, the second example at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms demonstrates how you can add custom classes for invalid/valid types, and show that a@b is indeed an invalid value.